# I want to be able to download a directory on S3 as a zipped file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

So basically I have a directory on S3 lets say `dir/` which contains a bunch of images and videos. I want to be able to download the whole directory as a `dir.zip` file. What would be the best way to do this?

Would prefer a language agnostic solution. If not I am working with Python.

Comment: Directories on S3 aren’t real, s3 just has objects with paths, so there’s no out of the box solution for this. You can create a system wherein you pre zip contents and retrieve them; but that probably creates more problems than it solves

Comment: Yes, i was considering maybe write a lambda which gets the data from s3 and creates the zip for me. But that seems overkill and doesn't seem scalable because of the 512mb lambda limit.

Comment: Download where? Into lambda environment?

Comment: Yes, something like that. But seems overkill